# Compute coefficients of a monomial

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

In the help of Mathematica, we can use `Coefficient[(x + 1)^3, x, 2]` to compute coefficients of x. I would like to define a function f such that $f(1/3*x[1,2]^3*c[1])=1/3$, $f(3*x)=3$ and so on. How could I do this in Mathematica? Thank you very much.

Comment: Something like `Cases[1/3 ∗x[1, 2]^3 ∗c[1] , f_?NumericQ, {1}]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks, thank you very much. But Cases[ x[1, 2]^3 , f_?NumericQ, {1}] returns 3. I want Cases[ x[1, 2]^3 , f_?NumericQ, {1}] = 1.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
First@FactorTermsList[1/2*x[1, 2]^3*c[1]]
First@FactorTermsList[3 x]
First@FactorTermsList[x[1, 2]^3]
(*
  1/2
  3
  1
*)
```

Comment: Michael, does my pattern work on your system?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yep, both V10.4 & V10.2.  (Of course, it does.)  And the OP's counterclaim yields `1/2`, not `c[1]`.  I think he set `f` to be `HoldAll`, as you probably suspect, too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what you want, but I think you can build this using recursion and pattern matching:

```
Clear[f]    
f[a_ * b_] := f[a] * f[b]
f[a_ + b_] := f[a] + f[b]
f[a_ ^ b_] := f[a]
f[a_?NumericQ] := a
f[s_Symbol] := 1
f[s_Symbol[___]] := 1
```

(There are probably examples where it doesn't behave the way you expect, but it should be clear how to modify/extend this.)

Note: The last replacement `f[s_Symbol[___]] := 1` will match patterns like `f[3+x]`, because that's just a short form for `f[Plus[3,x]]`. Be sure to match all arithmetic operations before that, or they will be replaced with 1

Answer (score 2):

My best guess:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[a_.*x___] := a
```

Now:

```
f[1/2*x[1, 2]^3*c[1]]

f[3*x]

f[x[1, 2]^3]
```

> ```
> 1/2
>
> 3
>
> 1
> ```

Be aware that `Times` will reorder expressions due to the [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) attribute;
if from `f[c[1]*1/2*x[1, 2]^3]` you want `c[1]` you will need to also define:

```
Attributes[f] = HoldAll;
```

Comment: thank you very much. I want f[c[1]*1/2*x[1, 2]^3] = 1/2.

Comment: @JianrongLi That is what my function returns with that input.  Is something wrong?

Comment: I computed in Mathematica and the result is  f[c[1]*1/2*x[1, 2]^3] = c[1].

Comment: @JianrongLi And you *did* evaluate `ClearAll[f]` but *did not* evaluate `Attributes[f] = HoldAll;`?  Which version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: I use Mathematica 10.3.